# If A mass is much bigger than B, and C mass is much, much bigger than B, Why if A and C hit B(with the same speed), B would have the same speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, collision

I saw that if $M \gg m$ (if the mass is much, much larger than the other one), then if $V_M$ (the initial velocity) is equal to $V_M'$ (the final velocity), $V_m=2V_m'$. Why does this happen?

Comment: Take the limit of $\frac mM\to 0$ in the final velocities of the collision.

Comment: Is this always true? When Vm=0, this implies that the smaller mass doesn't move after collision with a larger mass. If m is moving and M is a large stationary mass (a wall), this implies that m is moving at half its speed in the same direction after collision, which would mean that m moves straight through the wall somehow. Neither of those situations make sense.

Comment: Not clear. If you are asking a question about a problem you are working on then you should state the problem in full in your question, so that we know what you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get much bigger than much bigger. The phrase "much bigger" implies that the quantity is big enough to approximate some kind of asymptotic behavior. If a quantity is large enough to be considered "much bigger" than something else, you should not see a qualitatively different behavior when considering a quantity even larger than that, or other quantities of similar size. You will get numerically different answers with different quantities, but the differences will be "small" in relation to the other quantities in the equation.

We have A >> B and C >> B. If A and C are indeed both "much bigger" than B, we should see the same effects for both. If we don't, then A or C are not properly characterized as "much bigger" than B, since we haven't achieved any kind of asymptotic behavior where going even larger has minimal effect.

Comment: Why if A(1000kg), B(1kg) and C(10000kg), if they hit B with the same speed, B final velocity will be the same?

Comment: If A and C hit B with same velocity, final velocity of B will not be same

Comment: @MitulAgrawal Can you prove that?

Comment: @MitulAgrawal Numerically, yes, there will be a difference, but it will be a "small" one, relative to the quantities used. In an elastic collision where the smaller mass is stationary, as the ratio of the larger mass to the smaller one approaches infinity, the larger mass has 0 change in speed and the smaller one moves away with 2x the speed of the larger body. When the mass ratio is 1000:1, the smaller body's speed is 1.998v, when it's 10000:1, it's 1.9998v. We changed the input mass by 1000%, and saw the answer change by only 0.1%.

Comment: Yes @NuclearWang you are right difference is small.............@JoséGarcía Yes I can prove............eq 1 : e = 1 = (Vb-Va)/Ua.......eq 2 : MaUa = MbVb + MaVa........using this you can obtain Vb when A collides, similarly do for C......verify answer from comment by Nuclear Wang

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @NuclearWang, it makes more sense now. In the Q A and C >>B so difference in velocity of B tends to 0.

Comment: @MitulAgrawal Exactly right - the fact that we can call A "much bigger" than B implies that using an even larger value won't change the result much. If it *does* have a major effect, then A is not really "much bigger" than B. As long as a value is big enough to be called "much bigger", it doesn't really matter what the exact number is.

Answer (score 1):

In a collision (in the absence of external forces) the velocity of the center of mass does not change.  If one mass is much larger, the velocity of the center is much the same as that of the larger mass.  If the collision is elastic, the speed of the smaller mass, relative to the center of mass, is the same before and after the collision (but reversed).  In your problem, if the speeds of the two larger masses are the same, then the speeds of the centers of mass and the rebounding small masses will be nearly the same.